Tufte-LaTeX fork customized for ETbb fonts and 10pt, 11pt and 12pt font sizes
In November 2023 I found a fork of Tufte-LaTeX customized for ETbb fonts and 10pt, 11pt and 12pt font sizes. It is a very useful extension to Tufte-LaTeX and I would like to acknowledge the author. Now I cannot find it anywhere on the WWW, and there is no indication in the documentation about the identity of the author. Does anyone know whether this package is still available and, if so, where it lives?
